# Player-Sprite with hat/robe/staff for each direction?

Tags: animation, sprite

Some friends and I started to create a game, in which a mage will be in the center of the screen, being able to run in all 4 directions (as it is a 2D game)+diagonals, so 8 directions total (so the level below the player is moving).

The mage should wear a hat, a robe, and a staff for now, of which there should be a hole lot more than just one.

Additionally the mage should have a walking animation of let's say 3 pictures.

So overall it would be:

```
8(directions)*3(walking animation)*k(hats)*n(robes)*m(staffs) = 24*k*n*m sprites
```

(Which are currently BufferedImages as PNG with alphachannel drawn on a canvas), which is like waaaay too much for my designer (because we want a hole lot of staffs, robes and hats, maybe later even add boots and stuff)

So my idea was to make a "naked" playersprite and have separate sprites for staffs, robes and hats, which I then just render on top of the player.

Is that a good idea, or am I missing anything that would make all that a hole lot easier?

Comment: We cannot advise you on this as we do not know how the sprites will be used (how many, how fast, platform, ...)

Comment: I would consider posting this question on [Game Development Site](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com), you are more likely to receive solution.

Comment: Yes this is probably the best approach. To adjust the position of the hat f.e. when the mage moves forward you could implement something like an animation-listener that will be called on each frame change. There you can move the hat when the mage bends down or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

Combining sprites to draw the player is the way to go. You can reduce the amount of work more if you sacrifice some details.

- You can mirror the animation for left and right. The weapon is always in the players hand facing you (instead of e.g. always in the player's right hand)
- You can omit diagonal walking animations. Just reuse the horizontal or vertical animations.
- Some games even omit the vertical walking animations, meaning you always see the player from the side even though you can walk up. It may interferes with the game mechanics if you can't attack up or down.
- If the sprites are high res enough, you can keep static items as one single sprite and move/rotate them with the player's animation. So every weapon (or weapon type) has the same animation for walking, attacking etc. Probably doesn't look to good in retro style games because it won't be pixel perfect.
- Reuse sprites. Not every robe needs a new design, just change some colors.

If you plan on finishing the game, detailed sprites and animations should be the last thing you implement. Make an ugly prototype first and if it is fun, then you can still add more details and make it look good.

Comment: Hey, ok sounds good.
It seems to be just the best way to be able to add more stuff to the game with just needed one image and not hundreds.